# How increase autoscalling group step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have set up autoscalling group to reach `150` EC2 instances. So it begin to spin up about 20 instances per minute:

[image]

Is there way to setup aws for spinning `50` or `100` instances per minute?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried changing the **Default Cooldown** for the autoscaling group?

See this reference about scaling cooldowns

[Scaling Cool Down](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html)

Comment: it did not help. AWS instantiates +10 intances, wait some time and crates new +10, even when I decreased `DefaultCooldown` to `0` value. :(

Comment: It may be a safety feature put in by AWS to make sure customers are not abusing the autoscaling feature. I would assume they would hope you would plan accordingly and pick the correct EC2 instances that will handle the workload of your application. You could put in a support ticket with AWS to see what they would recommend for this.